# Using NDBs ComputedProperty to count another model's objects via ancestor query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am leveraging NDBs ComputedProperty and an ancestor query to count another model's objects that match a particular filter. The ComputedProperty looks something like this:

```
class Goal(ndb.Model):
    various_attributes = various_properties
    @ndb.ComputedProperty
    def count_active_actions(self):
        return Action.query(ancestor=self.key).filter(
                Action.status=='active').count()

class Action(ndb.Model):
    status = ndb.StringProperty(choices=(
            'not started', 'active', 'completed', 'on hold'))
    various_attributes = various_properties
    @ndb.ComputedProperty(
    def count_active_tasks(self):
        return Task.query(ancestor=self.key).filter(
                Task.status=='active').count()

class Task(ndb.Model):
    status = ndb.StringProperty(choices=(
            'not started', 'active', 'completed', 'on hold'))
    various_attributes = various_properties
```

When I create a `Goal` object, I do not store anything as its parent. **Notice that I have a similar ComputedProperty on Goal as I do on Action. I receive no errors when goal.put() is executed when writing a goal.**

However when creating an action object, I store the parent as the `goal.key` like this:

```
action = Action(parent=goal.key, various_other_properties = various_other_values)
action.put()
```

When the action is written, the `ComputedProperty` query is being executed and given that the action has not been completely written, the `id` for action has not been assigned and thus is `None`.

The error I receive is:

```
BadValueError: Expected complete Key, got Key('Goal', '##########', 'Action', None)
```

The behavior makes sense given what I think is happening behind the scenes. However I am assuming that I am missing something or am approaching this problem incorrectly as this seems to me to be a common use case.

My desired goal is to have a property of a parent object represent the count of a child object that matches a certain criteria plus has the parent object's key as its ancestor.

Is there a better way to achieve this? or is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: At some point you are trying to save an entity with an incomplete ancestor key.  ie the ancestor probably has not been put.  I wouldn't approach your problem using a computed property.  It is quite possible down the track you will get a DeadlineExceededError (front facing requests are limited to 60secs) and then the put will fail.  What will you do then? This approach is unlikely to scale or deal with outages.  I personally would make count_active_tasks an IntegerProperty and every time you put Action, fire off a task to calculate the value.